# How to speed up read.coda?

Tags: r, jags, coda

I am working on a large dataset and needed to run [jags](https://people.stat.sc.edu/hansont/stat740/jags_user_manual.pdf) on the command line. The output file for each chain is up to 15G (even with `thin = 10`).

It is taking too long to read the coda output files with the `read.coda` function from the [coda](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coda/index.html) package.  I tried to use `thin = 10` with the `read.coda` function, but it takes as long.

Is there a way to speed up the `read.coda` function from the [coda](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coda/index.html) package?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/runjags/forum/general/thread/4a7dbe7f/